# sort the array and print the smallest number in inline assembly in visual studio

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I write the following code to read some numbers ranging from -15 to 15 from the user and the user may define how many numbers to enter. Then I bubble sort the array to get the smallest number. (Bubble sort because I will need to print other information) However, the code is not working. Here is my code.

```
// oops.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char message0[] = "How many numbers do you want to enter? \n";
char message1[] = "Enter the current reading: \n";
char message2[] = "Error!\n";
char message3[] = "The smallest number is: \n";
char format1[] = "%d";
char format2[] = "%s";;
int myarray[10000];
int No;
int counter;
int *p;
p = myarray - 1;

_asm{
        lea eax, message0
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4
//read how many numbers the user would like to input
        lea eax,counter
        push eax
        lea eax, format1
        push eax
        call scanf_s
        add esp,8

        mov No, 1
        mov ecx, counter
        mov ebx, 0
//read user's input
Input:      push ecx
            push No
            lea eax, message1
            push eax
           call printf
            add esp, 8

        lea eax, myarray[ebx]
        push eax
        lea eax, format1
        push eax
        call scanf_s

        add esp,8
//judge if the number is in the range of -15 to 15
JudgeInput: mov eax, myarray[ebx]
        cmp eax,-15
        jl Illegal
        cmp eax,15
        jle Legal

Illegal: lea eax,message2
     push eax
     call printf
     add esp,4
     pop ecx
     jmp Input


Legal:    add ebx,4
      inc No
      pop ecx
      loop Input

//bubble sort
mov esi, p
mov ecx, counter

outer : mov edx, ecx
inner : cmp edx, ecx
        jz exchangeNo
        mov eax, [esi + ecx * 4]

        mov ebx, [esi + edx * 4]
        cmp eax, ebx
        jnb exchangeNo
        mov[esi + ecx * 4], ebx
        mov[esi + edx * 4], eax

    exchangeNo :
        dec edx
            jnz inner
            loop outer



finish:
smallest: //print the smallest number  
      mov ebx,0
      lea eax,message3
      push eax
      lea eax, format2
      push eax
      call printf
      mov eax,0
      lea ebx,myarray
      sub ebx,4
      add ebx,No
      lea eax, [ebx]
      push eax
      lea eax,format1
      call printf
      add esp,16
}

return 0;
}
```

It would not return the smallest number. Sometimes it returns strange characters. I get really confusing. Additionally, when I enter negative numbers, the bubble sort seems not working well.

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Learn to use a debugger to single step your program and see where it goes wrong yourself.

Comment: i did it step by step and the information "Unhandled exception at...Access violation reading location..." would be given

Comment: At which instruction ... check why that instruction accesses invalid memory.

Comment: I would also suggest breaking this into pieces and checking each piece.  For example, delete all the asm code except the part that asks for "How many numbers."  Then drop back to c and printf `counter`.  If that works correctly, add back the part that inputs numbers, then drop back to c and printf your array.  If that works, add back the sort, but after executing the very first swap, drop back to c and printf the array and check out the swap.  Once you have narrowed down where the problem is coming from, finding it is much easier.

Comment: That bubble sort has wrong algorithm. I would swear I did see similar bug recently in other questions.... here it is, check my comment, it should give you hint as well. Plus the hint: *"set up fixed {4, 3, 2, 1} array and watch sort over it"* is valid for you too (maybe add negative -1 too). http://stackoverflow.com/q/41056854/4271923

Comment: Ahh, yes.  A good point: Start with sorting simple data sets: {1}, {1,2}, {2,1}, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Here is my updated code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char message0[] = "How many numbers do you want to enter? \n";
    char message1[] = "Enter the current reading: \n";
    char message2[] = "Error!\n";
    char message3[] = "\nThe smallest number is: ";
    char format1[] = "%d";
    char format2[] = "%s";;
    int myarray[10000];
    int No;
    int counter;
    int *p;
    p = myarray - 1;

    _asm{
        lea eax, message0
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 4

        lea eax,counter
        push eax
        lea eax, format1
        push eax
        call scanf_s
        add esp,8

    //get the user's input into the array
        mov No, 1
        mov ecx, counter
        mov ebx, 0

    Input:      
        push ecx
        push No
        lea eax, message1
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 8

        lea eax, myarray[ebx]
        push eax
        lea eax, format1
        push eax
        call scanf_s
        add esp,8
    //judge if the input is between -15 and 15
    JudgeInput: 
        mov eax, myarray[ebx]
        cmp eax,-15
        jl Illegal
        cmp eax,15
        jle Legal
    //if not, print out error message
    Illegal: 
         lea eax,message2
         push eax
         call printf
         add esp,4
         pop ecx
         jmp Input

    //if yes, loop again
    Legal:    
          add ebx,4
          inc No
          pop ecx
          loop Input

    //bubble sort
    mov esi, p
    mov ecx, counter
    //the outer loop
    outer : mov edx, ecx
    //the inner loop
    inner : cmp edx, ecx
        je exchangeNo
        mov eax, [esi + ecx * 4]
        mov ebx, [esi + edx * 4]
        cmp eax, ebx
        jge exchangeNo
        mov[esi + ecx * 4], ebx
        mov[esi + edx * 4], eax
    exchangeNo :
            dec edx
            jge inner
            loop outer



    finish:
    //find out the smallest number
    smallest :
        lea eax, message3
        push eax
        lea eax, format2
        push eax
        call printf

        lea ebx, myarray
        mov eax, [ebx]

        push eax
        lea eax, format1
        push eax
        call printf
        add esp, 16
    }
}
```